# Why is there almost never online multiplayer in indie games?

Tags: game-design, game-mechanics, game-industry

There are alot of which are local but very few who have online.

Comment: _"very few who have online"_ Sorry, but do you have any data that backs this statement?

Comment: Maybe because running a server costs money

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think "very few" is accurate, but aside from the semantics there it's likely that the highest reason is infrastructure.  Outside of PC (Mac and Linux) gaming where peer to peer is fairly easy, most gaming (mobile and console) requires a server-client multiplayer option, and running servers and paying for bandwidth to allow that is not cheap.  Indie developers typically have considerably smaller budgets and bottom lines.